# Can you enable a disabled button WITHOUT javascript?

Tags: html, css

I have a button that is disabled when the page loads. Is there a way to enable it based on some user action (like clicking a different button) using just HTML and CSS?

Comment: No, you can not.

Comment: It can be (sort-of) emulated, but it's not the same thing: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gxshbn5d/

Answer (score 1):

No, that would require making a lasting change to the DOM which JavaScript is the only thing that can achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not do that. Css is a style sheet. It isn't made to do actions. If you want to change stuff you need JavaScript. Why don't you want to use JavaScript?